# It's possible to skip tags if they have been already parsed and coninue with the newer ones in python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Let's suppose that I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="class1">
    <div class="some multiple classes here">
        <div class="some multiple classes here">
            <ul class="other classes">
                <li>
                    <div class="random">some text</div>
                    <div class="random1">some text1</div>
                    <div class="random2">some tex2t</div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="random">some text3</div>
                    <div class="random1">some text4</div>
                    <div class="random2">some text5</div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="random">some text6</div>
                    <div class="random1">some text7</div>
                    <div class="random2">some text8</div>
                </li>
                <!-- here can appear more <li></li> elements -->
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, in python, I made a function which is adding each message from the `div`s inside `li` tags in a list. So my lists will look like this:

```
messages_list = ['some text some text1 some text2', 'some text3 some text4 some text5', 'and so on..']
```

The function that I created uses selenium webdriver to get the content from the HTML and it looks like this:

```
def writeToChatTest(CHAT_URL):
    mydriver.get(CHAT_URL)

    message = "Some message to test"
    xpaths = {
        'textArea': "//*[@id='ipsTabs_elChatTabs_chatroom_panel']/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/textarea",
        'submitMessage': "//*[@id='ipsTabs_elChatTabs_chatroom_panel']/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/button"
    }
    time.sleep(5)
    rst_messages_list = []
    lis = mydriver.find_elements_by_xpath('//ul[@class="ipsList_reset cChatContainer"]/li')

    for li in lis:
        rst_messages_list.append(li.text)

    for unique_message in rst_messages_list:
        if "word" in unique_message:
            mydriver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['textArea']).clear()
            mydriver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['textArea']).send_keys(unique_message[0] + ": " + message)

            mydriver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['submitMessage']).click()
```

Now, the question that I'm asking is: is there any way of storing the last `li` tag parsed and check if there's a new one (or more) ? More, how can I make this check to be made continously?

The problem is that once I parsed the whole `li` tags, I'm not able to retrieve the new ones (it's a chat, so new `li`s appear pretty often).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each element has an unique ID so you could store the last li processed but it complicates things.

I would something like:

```
def writeToChatTest(CHAT_URL):
    mydriver.get(CHAT_URL)

    message = "Some message to test"
    xpaths = {
        'textArea': "//*[@id='ipsTabs_elChatTabs_chatroom_panel']/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/textarea",
        'submitMessage': "//*[@id='ipsTabs_elChatTabs_chatroom_panel']/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/button"
    }

    parsed_messages = []
    keepRunning = True
    while keepRunning:
        time.sleep(5)            
        lis = mydriver.find_elements_by_xpath('//ul[@class="ipsList_reset cChatContainer"]/li')

        rst_messages_list = []

        for li in lis:
            if li.id() not in parsed_messages:
                '''this will end nicely your test if the message 'end selenium test' is being sent in chat'''
                if li.text == 'end selenium test':
                    keepRunning = False
                rst_messages_list.append(li.text)
                parsed_messages.append(li.id())

        for unique_message in rst_messages_list:
            if "word" in unique_message:
                mydriver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['textArea']).clear()
                mydriver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['textArea']).send_keys(unique_message[0] + ": " + message)

                mydriver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['submitMessage']).click()
```

Comment: @thenoob, what special message are you talking about ? If I'm doing like you said, the message is send endlessly. BTW, it's `li._id`. Any ideas of why is this happenning ? I want to send the message only if `word` is being found

Comment: I was talking about a special message that will end 'nicely' your test session.
I've updated the example to respond only if newly found messages have `word` and not the ones already parsed
Better use the getter for id `id()` rather than the 'private' property `_id`